# Why does Internet explorer encode link urls on the fly, and how to stop that behavior?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I have a really annoying problem with IE (all versions from what I can tell). Every link produced from the server side (may it be a string with an a-tag, hyperlink etc.) gets encoded on IE.
Eg.
http://www.some-domain.com/my document.pdf gets a correct encoding to:
http://www.some-domain.com/my%20document.pdf
However if I decide to do that encoding myself on the server side we get:
http://www.some-domain.com/my%20document.pdf and IE encodes this (and that is the problem)
and we get:
http://www.some-domain.com/my%2520document.pdf and the result is a link that is not correct.

%25 = % => %2520 = %20

How can I stop this behaviour in IE? Every other browser i've tried does not do this.

Comment: Do you have a test case? I tried and it worked correctly

Comment: How did you try it? Did you send
http://www.some-domain.com/my%20document.pdf from the server?
That's exactly what I'm doing and IE encodes it to the wrong link.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the space with a `+` - browsers treat this as a space and it shouldn't need encoding.

http://www.example.com/my+document.pdf

Comment: Im using Asp.Net and HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode does't do + as space it do %20, and I don't want to take care of every single char conversion myself if I dont have to.